Как лучше реализовать систему переключения оружия C# Unity 2D?
Вопрос скорее не по коду, а типо по структуризации.
Предположим, есть несколько оружий. Для каждого оружия есть своя текстурка игрока с этим оружием




У каждого оружия разная точка выхода пули, короче конец ствола, muzzle.
И я бы хотел удобным образом сделать переключение оружий (т.е. смена текстур), а также изменение точки выстрела.
Ну т.е. для каждой текстуры отметить свой muzzle end.

Зависит от количества оружия. Если видов оружия около 10 или меньше, то самым простым будет создать пустые дочерние GameObject'ы для каждого вида оружия и спозиционировать каждый из них. Удобство заключается в визуализации позиции. Зареференсить их можно вместе со спрайтами в сериализуемом объекте, что-то типа:
[Serializable]
class Weapon {
    public Sprite sprite;
    public GameObject projectileSpawnPoint;
}

Иначе, можно сделать то же самое, только вместо GameObject'а просто задать позцию:
[Serializable]
class Weapon {
    public Sprite sprite;
    public Vector2 projectileSpawnPoint;
}

Положить это все можно, например, в List (тогда за вид оружия отвечает его индекс в списке):
public class WeaponSwitcher : MonoBeahviour {
    [SerializeField] List<Weapon> _weapon;
}

Ну и при переключении оружия вы сразу можете взять и спрайт, и позицию в нем.
